# request problems image on Power BI python script

Tags: python, powerbi

I am trying to do a heatmap over a map into a python script. The methodology is loading an image with a public URL of a webserver that contains this map.

In Power BI Desktop works well but when I publish this report, the request to load the map in PWBI is not working. I understand that power bi servers are not allowed to make requests to public URLs. The message error that returns python script is:

socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

The URL is public. Therefore, I do not understand why this image is not load. mark: the webserver is an azure service (blob container).

The library to make requests is matplotlib that internally contains urllib. Can you help me?

There are another way to load images in python scripts without Public URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a small number of images you can embed them in your Dataset or directly in your Python source code, converted to Base64.  See, eg [Storing Images in a PowerBI/Analysis Services Data Models](https://blog.gbrueckl.at/2018/01/storing-images-powerbi-analysis-services-data-models/).

Comment: Your idea is inspiring me to load the image as binary base64 string in python and then visualize it. Thanks